# Make the element inside each column to have same height using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, height

Is it possible to make the orange area to have the same height using bootstrap, as shown in the picture 1 below? even though the paragraph inside has different length? The structure I currently using is like following, and the result is as shown in picture2.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[image: picture1]
pic1

[image]
pic2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do here is set a height on your orange areas. Something like this will do the trick.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Kbf/)

```
.h3 {
    height: 150px;                /* Your height goes here */
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell;` Try this bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/CYMv8o29K3

Comment: this does not look like what @blake asked for.

Comment: I'm going off the title as I can't see the images attached from here.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with an additional div that wraps around the h3 tag. You can assign a minimum or fixed height to this div to achieve the desired result.

**CSS**

```
.orange {
   height: 200px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="orange">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="orange">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="orange">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You gain flexibility by not setting a predefined height (what if your text is really long). Try using the `map()` function to get the height of the tallest element and use this height for all elements with the same class. [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/KBJMeMr062)

Answer (score 0):

Just found a jquery plugin that solves this problem, so no need to set a fixed height in css.
http://filamentgroup.com/examples/equalHeights/